# Remove textbox that added dynamically (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am trying to delete a `TextBox` control **(that added dynamically)** in my form through `Button_Click` event **(that I added dynamically too)** but I cannot find the exact way to do it. My TextBox will added together with Button control **(delete button)** when a `LinkLabel` is clicked. So when added dynamically my `textbox.name` will be like `textbox_1`,`textbox_2`,`textbox_3` and along with them is a Button control like `btnDel1`,`btnDel2`,`btnDel3` (all placed in a Panel control).

My coding goes like this :

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
    Dim textbox As TextBox = TryCast(sender, TextBox)

    'In this case when btnDel1 is clicked, textbox_1 will be removed as well
    If button.Name = "btnDel1" Then
        PanelOthers.Controls.Remove(button)
    End If
End Sub
```

Button is removed successfully but how do I remove the textbox too? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. Attach all the relevant controls to the delete button's Tag property.
2. Create a user control that encapsulates the button and textbox.

### Option 1: the Tag property

When you create your controls, add the associated controls to the button's `.Tag` property:

```
Dim button As Button = New Button
Dim textbox As TextBox = New TextBox

button.Tag = {textbox}
'  Add the button and textbox to the UI surface
```

Now when the button is clicked you can loop over the associated controls and remove them too:

```
For Each item As Control In button.Tag
    item.Dispose()
Next
button.Dispose()
```

### Option 2: A user control

So isn't a tutorial site.. but you can do your own research on this one.

- Here's a place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c316f119%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: It's working all great using the `Tag` property. Thank you so much :)